# Why does my page scrolls every time I'm typing inside an input in SPFx?

Tags: reactjs, accordion, sharepoint-online, spfx, primereact

I'm working on an SPFx React functional component. I have created a component that contains many accordions Each accordion contains one textbox. Every time I'm typing anything inside an input the page scrolls to the top. Please refer to the below image for better understanding.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks